# Removing item from list in EF model

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework and I am trying to remove a NinjqEquiment from a list belonging to an instance of Ninja.When I retrieve the list of Ninjas,I make sure to include the equipment list, so I know they are there. Then I remove the equipment from the Ninja and try to save changes. I get the following error -

> The entity type List`1 is not part of the model for the current
>   context.

```
 using (var db = new NinjaDbContext())
        {
            //get ninjas with equipment included
            var ninjas = GetAllNinjas();

            //get ninja
            var ninja = (from n in ninjas
                         where n.Id == id
                         select n).FirstOrDefault();


            //get equipment
            var eq = (from e in ninja.EquipmentOwned
                      where e.Id == removeEqId
                      select e).FirstOrDefault();

            //remove eq from ninja
            ninja.EquipmentOwned.Remove(eq);

            //Make sure entity knows EquipmentOwned has been modified
            db.Entry(ninja.EquipmentOwned).State = EntityState.Modified;

            //save ninja
            db.SaveChanges();


        }
```

Comment: Are you getting value in `eq`? it is from DB or default one?

Comment: Yes i am. Its the correct item with the correct ID. Am i going about it the correct Entity Framework way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove this:

```
        //Make sure entity knows EquipmentOwned has been modified
        db.Entry(ninja.EquipmentOwned).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

This causes the error.

`EquipmentOwned` is a `List<Equipment>`. It is not an `Entry` in `EF` terms so it is not tracked directly by it.

When you delete an entity from such collection, `EF` knows that there won't be any relationship between this particular ninja and this particular equipment. It won't delete equipment from database because other ninjas may use this equipment.

To delete it completely you should remove this equipment from corresponding `DbSet<>` like this:

```
using (var db = new NinjaContext())
{
    //db.Equipment is a DbSet<Equipment>
    //id is PrimaryKey of Equipment table
    var eq = db.Equipment.Find(id);
    db.Equipment.Remove(eq);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: I understand the error then. Thanks, that is helpfull. But it doesnt solve my problem. This is in fact how i had the code before. It runs and i can see that the item is removed from the list before i call SaveChanges(). But it doesnt disapear from the DB. And no error is given. 

Maybe i should a new question about this.

Comment: @Lautaro It should not disappear from DB because NavigationCollection is a relationship, but not a `DbSet`. To remove it from DB you should remove it from `DbSet`. You don't have an error here, EF works as intended.

Comment: ok! So to remove the item from the Ninja-model is not the correct EF way then?

Comment: When i remove it from Dbset i get this error

The object cannot be deleted because it was not found in the ObjectStateManager.

Comment: @Lautaro I've updated my answer. To delete the object it should be in attached state. You could do it manually: `db.Entry(eq).State = EntityState.Attached;` or just `Find()` object in `DbSet<>` or something else. You should really read some book about EF.

Comment: I thought it would work anyway since i got the eq from the ninja which i got from the DB. But ill try your way. And yes, i will read more about EF.